# How to run Facebook authentication on localhost in Django?

Tags: django, django-facebook

I have read all discussion about this matter on StackOverFlow but all of them seem outdated.

Does anyone know how to run facebook authentication on localhost in Django by social-auth-app-django ?
 I have spent probably a day or so  trying to solve  it but nothing works.

[image]

[image]

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    "social_core.backends.vk.VKOAuth2",
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend"
)
SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE = 'social'

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',  
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
SOCIAL_AUTH_STRATEGY = 'social_django.strategy.DjangoStrategy'  # new
SOCIAL_AUTH_STORAGE = 'social_django.models.DjangoStorage'  # new


# facebook
#FACEBOOK_APP_ID = ' xxx'
#FACEBOOK_API_SECRET = ' xxx'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = ' xxx'  # new
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'xxx ' # new
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
            'fields': 'id,name,email',
            }
SOCIAL_AUTH_ADMIN_USER_SEARCH_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'email']

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware', # new
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',  # new
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

Comment: edit your `.hosts` file (not sure what the equivalent is on Windows) and add a line like `127.0.0.1 development.com`  This will get your pc looking for development.com at the ip 127.0.0.1.  Facebook accepts this

Comment: @HenryM. Thanks for the advice. I have done it. Nothing has changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run localhost as a ssl server.

```
pip install django-sslserver
```

Add the application to your INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (...
"sslserver",
...
)
```

And run:

```
python manage.py runsslserver
```